# Cardview's click event conflicts with NestedScrollView's scroll event

Tags: android

I put a `CardView` in a `NestedScrollView`,and use the below codes to make its ripple effect.

```
     android:clickable="true"
     android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

And I get the ripple effect successfully,but the click event conflicts with the scroll event so that when I put my finger in the cardview I can't scroll the NestedScrollView.

The `NestedScrollView` and the `Cardview` looks like this:

[image]

My core code are in the below code area.

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/item_to_left_right_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/item_to_left_right_margin"
        android:paddingTop="24dp">

    ，，，，，，
    ，，，，，，    
         <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/followerWrap"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/three_userlabel_height"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"                      
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                <com.quinn.githubknife.ui.widget.UserLabel
                    android:id="@+id/followersLabel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    userlabel:name="Followers"
                    userlabel:value="00" />

          </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

 </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Same issue here. Did you find the solution?